# Can I configure a software synth to use multiple patches on a channel?

Tags: midi, lilypond, synthesizer

I am writing music for organ in LilyPond and listening to it via the LilyPond MIDI output through Qsynth/FluidSynth. I've been using Fluid_R3, but it only has a very generic (and not very convincing) "Church Organ" patch. I recently found [JEUX](https://www.realmac.info/jeux1.htm), a soundfont with all sorts of organ stops, and I'd like to export a synthesis that works like a real organ, with multiple patches registered on each channel.

Is there a straightforward way to configure FluidSynth (or a similar software synth) to apply multiple patches on a single MIDI channel? If so, would I have to do something special in LilyPond for its MIDI output to work? (I could do something like multiple exports and add the sound files together, but that's a lot of complication!)

Comment: Given the synth you're using, you're are using gnu/Linux right?

Comment: @Tom Yes, I'm on GNU/Linux. FluidSynth because it's something of a default, but I'm open to alternatives.

Comment: Maybe qmidiroute could help you? That's a midi utility that can route midi signals depending on conditions, for instance to another channel or things like that... I did not understand exactly what you wanted to do but Could be worth a try! You can intercalate it between LP and qsynth.

Comment: @Tom Hmm, checking that out! I am wanting to do this in CLI mode to produce a "recording"; do you know offhand whether it would work sensibly in that context?

Comment: Cli?  Command line? If so, all these tools are compatible for that! That's part of the alsa library suite.

Comment: Can you use jack to route MIDI? Then perhaps you can use it to route MIDI signal to multiple fluidsynth instances? Anyway, unless I miss something, Lilypond doesn't seem to me a tool made to generate high quality audio output.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking in principle, MIDI specifications allow only one patch per channel. You can change the patch as often as you want, you can set a different patch before every note you play, but a channel can only have a single patch at any time.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but while MIDI can send Program Change commands, I can certainly imagine a means to provide a channel mapping that would be used instead. Program Change is a side-channel to the actual instrument events.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-  Program Change is an actual instrument event, just like Note On. "_The Program Change message is used to specify the type of instrument which should be used to play sounds on a given Channel._" https://www.midi.org/midi-articles/about-midi-part-3-midi-messages MIDI channel number is a part of the Program Change message.